# Windows 7 keeps changing wireless adapter DNS to 192.168.100.10

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-7

Windows 7 keeps changing my wireless adapter DNS to 192.168.100.10. This usually happens when I log on to different wifi connection. Sometimes it's a coffee shop, work or home. Anyone have an idea how I can stop this?

I specify google DNS, but it gets changed.

Primary : 8.8.8.8
Secondary : 8.8.4.4

### Here is my research effort :

[Google Link to My Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+7+assigns+dns+to+adapter&aq=f&oq=windows+7+assigns+dns+to+adapter&aqs=chrome.0.57.5866&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&gs_rn=7&gs_ri=psy-ab&gs_mss=Windows%207keeps%20changing%20dns%20to%20192.168.100.10&tok=CJ2B28k1XDcm_gBMWS_rxw&pq=keeps%20changing%20dns%20to%20192.168.100.10&cp=10&gs_id=h2&xhr=t&q=Windows%207%20keeps%20changing%20dns%20to%20192.168.100.10&es_nrs=true&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&oq=Windows+7+keeps+changing+dns+to+192.168.100.10&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44158598,d.aWM&fp=d76eed8efe782f95&biw=1280&bih=875) As yo ucan see there are no issues related to the problem I am having

Comment: Your down votes are most likely from not reading the FAQ and posting a  non professional system administration question.

Comment: Okay, thank you for telling me that, I was under the impression that this was the spot to post it. I would love to delete the question, but it looks like I don't have the option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By not connecting to strange wifi connections.

You're picking up a DNS server by DHCP, which, you can reconfigure under your network adapter settings to use a specific DNS server or servers, rather than a DHCP-supplied one.  Of course, you risk not being able to connect to your DNS server of choice (and therefore lose the ability to browse the web in general) if you run into a captive portal that's relying on using its DNS server to direct you to a login page.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It gets changed even when I have specified a DNS.  I typically use Google's DNS

Comment: Do you use OpenVPN?

Comment: We use Watchguard VPN. We actually have been on tech support calls with them about this. But the are saying that it is not anything that Watchguard is doing